# How to create Cookie (with static values) to add this to CookieContainer in .Net 4.5 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, .net-4.5

How can I create Cookie (with static values) to add this to CookieContainer in .Net 4.5 in C#?

HttpCookie not exists in .Net 4.5 in my Visual Studio 2013 Express

I wanted to do it via:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
myCookie["Font"] = "Arial";
myCookie["Color"] = "Blue";
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
```

But I cant because of error (HttpCookie not exists in System.Web)

Comment: Can you post the exact error? The `HttpCookie` class does exist in `System.Web` in .NET 4.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The type or namespace name 'HttpCookie' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you do not have referenced assembly `System.Web` in your project (maybe you have not selected right project type) - you can check in **References** through **Solution Explorer**. However if you would like to have `HttpCookie` available in your current project, you have to add reference to the project manually - throught **Solution Explorer** -> **References** -> **Add Reference** -> **Assemblies** -> **Framework** -> select `System.Web`. After this step, you should be able to resolve your problem (assuming that you will insert statement `using System.Web` in your class.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are accessing the cookies from class different from the one who extend the page class which is related to a specific context at run time,the compiler doesn't know which context you are addressing unless you specify it explicitly by using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("UserSettings", "whatever"));
```

usually you need this   HttpContext.Current.Response  when you are using helper class with a static method that deal with the cookies

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `System.Web` namespace. At the top of your file you should see a list of namespaces you're using, something like:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
```

To use the HttpCookie class, you need to add:

```
using System.Web;
```

Comment: Right click on the word HttpCookie and select Resolve -> Using ***, where *** is whatever it says.

Comment: I can only generate a new class, which mean creating new class with name "HttpCookie".